# How to write my full name in English?

Tags: names

My first name is Thu, my middle name is Thi and my last name (which is also my father's name) is BUI.

How should I write my full name:

- Thi - Thu BUI
- Thu Thi Bui

Comment: You put your given name in first position and your family name in last position, only capitalizing the first letter of each name, not all the letters.  Also, if your name is from an Asian language and employs a hyphen, the first letter after the hyphen isn't normally hyphenated, for example, we write the leader of North Korea's name "Kim Jong-un," not "Kim Jong-Un."  Kim, of course, is his family name because he's made no attempt to anglicize the format of his name.

Comment: Xin chau! I also suspect you might have done a typo, is your last name Bui or a Nui (as it is in your profile)?